# p2 repository with log4j2x

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, p2

Earlier eclipse rcp workspace is referring to the target having log4j1.2.15 version. Below are the reference links.

eclipse latest p2 repository:(does not have the log4j)
ref1:https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.17-I-builds/I20200817-0920/plugins/

p2 repo with log4j 12.15 version
ref2:
https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/archive/reports/download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06/http___download.eclipse.org_releases_2020-06_202006171000/org.apache.log4j_1.2.15.v201012070815.html

From which p2 repository , we can find the log4j2 version jars (log4j2xapi, log4j2xcore).

Or is there any way to build jars and update corporate p2 repo instead of eclipse p2 repo

Answer (score 1):

You use an **integration** (a kind of nightly build) repository for the future release, which will be deleted one day. If you don't want to test upfront whether your application will work with the future Eclipse release, better use a **release** repository instead.

Anyway, use the Eclipse project (the Eclipse platform and [JDT](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/)) repository and if something is missing, check out the more comprehensive simultaneous release repository. If it is missing there as well, see if you can find it in Eclipse Orbit:

1. **Eclipse Project**: `https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/<eclipse-platform-version>/` (currently, the Eclipse platform version of the current release is `4.16` and of the upcoming release is `4.17`)
2. **Simultaneous Release**: `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/<release-name>/` (currently, the current release is `2020-06` and the upcoming release is `2020-09`) - in your case, also the repository for the upcoming release currently contains log4j
3. [**Eclipse Orbit**](https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/)

Comment: both places mentioned by howlger dont have latest log4j, looks like eclipse not upgrading the log4j .

Comment: @user961524 The Eclipse project (platform + JDT) got rid of the log4j dependency and other Eclipse projects participating in the simultaneous release may follow. So you might build your own log4j OSGi bundle.

Comment: howlger, how to build own log4j OSGi bundle for log4j2 which included multiple jars?

Comment: @user961524 There is _File > New > Other...: Plug-in Development > Plug-in from Exisiting JAR Archive_ for that. But since there is already an older version that works, I would recommend modifying the old one instead.

Comment: modifying the old one instead , old has single jar for log4j1x but log4j2x has more than 2jars